# Search by date with jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am working with Jqgrid on C# and I have an issue when I try
to search by Date because the field 'fecha' in the colModel is a Datetime on the Entity
so, the value that the grid get from json looks like: /Date(1514869200000)/
but with the "formatter: 'date'" the value looks like: 02/01/2018.

When I try to search, the field search by the original value (/Date(1514869200000))
and no as a Date that is that I want

Sorry for my bad English, I hope someone understand me.

Here is my .js

```
$(function () {
$('#grid').jqGrid({
    url: "/Empleados/BuscarEmpleados",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'Get',
    colNames: ['ID', 'Nombre', 'Cargo', 'Móvil', 'Fecha Inicio', 'Estado', 'Opciones'],
    colModel: [
        { label: "ID", key: true, name: 'id', index: 'id', width: '100px' },
        { label: 'Nombre', name: 'nombre', index: 'nombre', width: '280px', searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn', 'eq'] } },
        { label: 'Cargo', name: 'cargo', index: 'cargo', width: '160px', searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn', 'eq'] } },
        { label: 'Movil', name: 'movil', index: 'movil', width: '140px', searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn', 'eq'] } },
        { label: 'Fecha Inicio', name: 'fecha', index: 'fecha', formatter: 'date',
            formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y', srcformat: 'd/m/Y' }, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn', 'eq', 'gt'] }, width: '150px' },
        { name: 'estado', index: 'estado', width: '155px', search: false },
        { name: 'Opciones', index: 'Opciones', formatter: OpcionesEmpleado, search: false, width: '300px' }
    ],
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
    height: "100%",
    viewRecords: true,
    loadonce: true,
    caption: "Empleados",
    emptyRecords: "No se han encontrado coincidencias",
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false
    },
    autowidth: true,
    multiselect: false,
}).navGrid('#pager', {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    search: true,
    refresh: true
});
```

Comment: Please include in all questions about jqGrid the information about **the version** of jqGrid, which you use, and the **fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thanks for your answer. I'm using JqGrid v4.4.4. I already try to add the sorttype: 'date' property and the search does not work. Have you another idea of what could be happening? Thanks

Comment: Why you use the version which is more as **5 years old**? If you use jqGrid from NuGet then you can deinstall the retro version and install [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) 4.15.3 package. I'd recommend you to look at [the page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) additionally. Adding `sorttype: 'date'` should solve your problem if you would use the current version of free jqGrid. I'd recommend you to look at the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/su7ebs65/ to see some new possibilities.

Comment: I was using v4.4.4 because i follow a google tutorial to use it and they propose to use jquery.jqGrid by Trirand haha. But now, I install the version you said and finally the filter works for all the columns. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
sorttype: "date"
```

property to the definition of the column `fecha` (the column with the date).